# Can't alter DisplayMember in WinForms ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to alter how a combobox is displayed using the following code:

```
    private void UpdateMapRoadPointList(List<GeographicAddress> plstMapRoadPointList)
    {
        cboFind.DataSource = plstMapRoadPointList;
        cboFind.DisplayMember = "ShortCode";
        cboFind.ValueMember = "";
    }
```

GeographicAddress is a class which has a ShortCode property which returns a string:

```
    internal string ShortCode
    {
        get { return Distance + Carriageway; }
    }
```

However, when using the application, the disaplyed value is still coming from GeographicAddress.ToString().  On debugging, it seems that cboFind.DisplayMember = "ShortCode" is having no effect!  DisplayMember is "" before and after executing that line!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public string ShortCode
    {
        get { return Distance + Carriageway; }
    }

private void UpdateMapRoadPointList(List<GeographicAddress> plstMapRoadPointList)
    {
        cboFind.DataSource = plstMapRoadPointList;
        cboFind.DisplayMember = "ShortCode";
    }
```

this should work

Set `ShortCode` property to Public or it will fail and use `GeographicAddress.ToString()`

Comment: Yeah - the property needed to be public.  Silly me!